# converting DataFrame to Matrix in sparkr

Tags: r, sparkr

I am trying to convert spark datafame(contains 2 columns) to Matrix. But I felt the approch I have used may not be correct, Also matrix was not created. Could you please advise me on how do we convert spark dataFrame to Matrix and vice-versa.

```
result1 <- read.df('/home/xxx/yyy/zzz', "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")

result1= result1[,-1]

MD2 = result1

registerTempTable(MD2, "md2")

temp1 <- sql("select SO_Order , count(distinct SKU) AS SKU_cnt from md2 group by SO_Order")

registerTempTable(temp1, "tmp1")

temp2 = sql("select * from tmp1 where SKU_cnt >1")
mydata = unique(MD2[,c(1,2)])
mydata1 <- collect(select(mydata, "SO_Order_x"))
mydata2 <- collect(select(mydata, "SKU"))
mymatrix <- cbind(mydata1, mydata2)
```

but the matrix was not created. Could you please advise me. Appreciate your quick help. Thanks in advance.

Thanks.